What is the best metric to use to discard annotators with low IAA (inter-annotator agreement) with all others?
This question is specific to ordinal data collected on the likert scale
What is the best metric to discard annotators with low inter-annotator agreement (IAA) with others? from e.g., Cohen’s Kappa, Fleiss’ Kappa, Krippendorff’s Alpha
Is it better to calculate the inter-annotator agreement pairwise for each pair of annotators or is it possible to do 1 annotator vs others?
